# A lot of deleted docs will Influence the speed of query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to delete docs frequent,but `es` only flags these as deleted.If there are a lot of deleted docs,the speed of query will lower?Has other problems?

**EDIT**

In other words,I often delete a lot of docs from a `index`,and never use `force merge` api to release disk usage,i will have query performance issues after a period of time?

Comment: check these settings https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must simply send an http `POST` request to your elasticsearch node, in below structure

`http://localhost:9200/your_index_name/_forcemerge`

for more details you can read this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html)

> If there are a lot of deleted docs,the speed of query will lower?

the answer is yes

> In other words,I often delete a lot of docs from a index,and never use force merge api to release disk usage,i will have query performance issues after a period of time?

elasticsearch automatically run merge process when insert or update operations is too high (that causes segments being dirty). in other hand you can use `forcemerge` api to have some controls on merging process yourself.

Comment: I tried 'force merge',but the number of deleted docs just from 5 million to 3 million,I can clear the deleted docs?

Comment: I tried it myself, force merge remove only the deleted docs, in my case older version of documents still remains. I use `hq` [plugin](http://www.elastichq.org/support_plugin.html) to get information about my nodes. it's shows me that the deleted document after `forcemerge` is `0%`

Answer (score 1):

Documents are stored in the index as segments which are formed when the document is created in lucene. Deleting the document from elastic don't actually delete the document from the underlying segment, which forms the basic data storage for ES.

Yes having lot of deleted documents will have query performance issues as the query will still search for matched documents in the deleted segments as well.

[Force_merge or optimize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) the index is usually the option to do about it, but you should take little care to handle this as this is heavy disk i/o operation.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/kimchy,elasticsearch/_optimize'

$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

Can you explain more why you have so many deletes frequently. As we also had huge deletes frequently, but we handled them on index level. Our deletes happens for documents for certain date-range , so we indexes the documents based on dates and when the time comes to delete the doc for certain date we just simply drop the index.

If you have any pattern for the documents to be deleted, i suggest you separate them out in a index and just drop the index